# PHP DOMDocument::getElementById fails with DOMDocumentFragment

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementbyid

I just want to know why this fails. This is the testcase:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id='testId'>Test</div></body></html>");
echo "This works: ".$doc->getElementById('testId')->nodeValue.'<br/>';

$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML("<p id='testId2'>Test 2</p>");
$doc->getElementById('testId')->appendChild($fragment);

echo "This still works: ".$doc->getElementById('testId')->nodeValue.'<br/>';
echo "This doesn't work: ".$doc->getElementById('testId2')->nodeValue.'<br/>';
```

The workaround is to use

```php
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@id="testId2"]')[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Does not fail. You check for `testId`, but want to search for `testId2`.

Comment: I don't think so. $doc->getElementById('testId2') returns null and, in my opinion, it should have found <p id='testId2'> node, but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [original DOM 2.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/#core-ID-getElBId) says:

> **`getElementById` introduced in DOM Level 2**
>
> Returns the Element whose ID is given by `elementId`. If no such element exists, returns `null`. Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this ID.
>
> Note: The DOM implementation must have information that says which attributes are of type ID. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined. Implementations that do not know whether attributes are of type ID or not are expected to return `null`.

The important part of that is *Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined.*

When you're working with HTML, the built-in [DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd) defines "id" as the element ID attribute:

```xml
<!ENTITY % coreattrs
 "id          ID             #IMPLIED  -- document-wide unique id --
  class       CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- space-separated list of classes --
  style       %StyleSheet;   #IMPLIED  -- associated style info --
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- advisory title --"
  >
```

However, when you append elements to a document fragment using `DomDocumentFragment::appendXML()` you are using raw XML, which has no such DTD. (This doesn't really seem intuitive, since you've appended it to an HTML document, but the whole DomDocument API is far from intuitive!)

PHP does address this in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) for `DomDocument::createGetElementById()`:

> For this function to work, you will need either to set some ID attributes with `DOMElement::setIdAttribute` or a DTD which defines an attribute to be of type ID.

So, the solution is to simply tell the parser that the `id` attribute is, in fact, the ID attribute:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id='testId'>Test</div></body></html>");
echo "This works: ".$doc->getElementById('testId')->nodeValue.'<br/>';

$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML("<p id='testId2'>Test 2</p>");
// here's the magic
$fragment->childNodes[0]->setIdAttribute("id", true);
$doc->getElementById('testId')->appendChild($fragment);

echo "This still works: ".$doc->getElementById('testId')->nodeValue.'<br/>';
echo "And so does this: ".$doc->getElementById('testId2')->nodeValue.'<br/>';
```

Comment: Going through these 20 year old specs brought back a lot of memories! SGML is very ancient, but it still influenced HTML a lot, including its eccentricities. This was a complete and valid document back in the 90s! `<html><title>Foo</title><b>Foo</>`